# Why React Stripe CardElement not rendering?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I was coding a project using React. It's been 3 days I've looking for a solution. I learned to code and tried to integrate the stripe payment option on my web app. However, unable to get the proper result. I searched a lot but found no solution.
This is My App.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./Header";
import Home from "./Home";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Checkout from "./Checkout";
import Login from "./Login";
import Payment from "./Payment";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "./firebase.js";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";

const stripePromise = loadStripe(
  "pk_test_51Ku8iiSHAST6F5x2egU8YwHdYkqKAOcJIfrfXKa0b7kxeHm0ECkvFOLVW0KeaiudzfAfU31m954rOkIKGsoXhiAE00EQx04Did"
);

function App() {
  const [{}, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  const auth = getAuth();
  useEffect(() => {
    // will only run once when the app component loads...
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      console.log("THE USER IS >>> ", user);
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
        // ...
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user: user,
        });
      } else {
        // User is signed out
        // ...
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user: null,
        });
      }
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    // BEM
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/checkout" element={[<Header />, <Checkout />]} />
          <Route
            path="/payment"
            element={[
              <Header />,
              <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
                <Payment />
              </Elements>,
            ]}
          />
          <Route path="/" element={[<Header />, <Home />]} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
//https://cloned-4270b.web.app
```

this is my Payment.js where CardElement is written.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./Payment.css";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import CheckoutProduct from "./CheckoutProduct";
import { CardElement, useStripe, useElements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";

function Payment() {
  const [{ basket, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  return (
    <div className="payment">
      <div className="payment__container">
        <h1>
          Checkout (<Link to="/checkout">{basket?.length} items</Link>)
        </h1>

        {/* Payment section - delivery address */}
        <div className="payment__section">
          <div className="payment__title">
            <h3>Delivery Address</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="payment__address">
            <p>{user?.email}</p>
            <p>123 React Lane</p>
            <p>Los Angeles, CA</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        {/* Payment section - Review Items */}
        <div className="payment__section">
          <div className="payment__title">
            <h3>Review items and delivery</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="payment__items">
            {basket.map((item) => (
              <CheckoutProduct
                id={item.id}
                title={item.title}
                image={item.image}
                price={item.price}
                rating={item.rating}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>

        {/* Payment section - Payment method */}
        <div className="payment__section">
          <div className="payment__title">
            <h3>Payment Method</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="payment__details">
            {/* Stripe magic will go */}
            <CardElement />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Payment;
```

version using stripe:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.6.2",
    "@mui/material": "^5.6.4",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.7.2",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.29.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "firebase": "^9.8.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-currency-format": "^1.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
```

After every attempts, CardElement is not rendering in the image below
[image: Payment component where CardElemt should be shown near Payment Method]

Comment: Hey, could you please share any errors you are getting on your console?

Comment: Alright i will send it during the daytime. Kindly wait for the time being

Answer (score 0):

I think when you add `flex-direction : column;` to the css of the `payment_section` , the `CardElement` started rendering,
or you can change the display to block or flow in that case its also rendering.